# How to reduce height of twitter bootstrap nav bar when using brand logo rather than font logo

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap but have a problem with the nav bar height - css.

I want to reduce the height of the nav bar to 30px but when I use an img logo the nav bar will not reduce in height. I have reduced logo size but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Totally stumped and annoyed.

Comment: are you using the sass or less version?

Comment: i am using less version.

Comment: You have to change the padding for the logotype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please read this topic on changing navbar height: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1540

Comment: Thank you, I saw this a few weeks ago after going crazy digging around for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The fool-proof method is to modify the style directly within the html tag, for example:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="height: 30px">
  // logo here
</div>
```

Comment: I know it's kinda old, but I managed to get it work when used on `navbar-inner`, not `navbar`

Comment: with navbar-inner the navigation links appear below the navbar